# Replacing values in the results of a SELECT with values from the same SELECT/table/different column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

my apologies in advance if I struggle to articulate my issue succinctly.

Problem: I have an issue where certain fields are blank in a view being used for data visualisation.

Unfortunately my current set up, the way that it is, is I cannot update or change any underlying data (I originally wrote a cursor to fix this issue and have since found out I cannot run it!)

To Be:

Let's say I have a table that I want to look like this.

| PartName | PartNumber | PartDescription | ProjectDescription | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Screw | A1234 | Screw - 25mm | Garden Shed | 4.00 |
| Screw | A1234 | Screw - 25mm | Garden Shed | 16.00 |
| Screw | A1234 | Screw - 25mm | Garden Shed | 4.00 |
| Bolt | B4321 | Bolt x4 | Project Scaffold | 164.00 |
| Bolt | B4321 | Bolt x4 | Project Scaffold | 8.00 |
| Bolt | B4321 | Bolt x4 | Project Scaffold | 32.00 |

As Is:

But unfortunately, due to... reasons, my data actually looks something like this:

| PartName | PartNumber | PartDescription | ProjectDescription | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Garden Shed | MISSING | MISSING | MISSING | 4.00 |
| Screw | A1234 | Screw - 25mm | Garden Shed | 16.00 |
| Screw | A1234 | Screw - 25mm | Garden Shed | 4.00 |
| Bolt | B4321 | Bolt x4 | Project Scaffold | 164.00 |
| Project Scaffold | MISSING | MISSING | MISSING | 8.00 |
| Bolt | B4321 | Bolt x4 | Project Scaffold | 32.00 |

So as you can see, there is data that links the broken rows to the correct data:

Name = Description2

And I need to populate the MISSING fields with the correct data so come data visualisation time a group by would work as intended.

I'm pretty sure the DV tool I'm using won't allow for the use of CTEs but I can create a new view to publish.

As I said, I created a cursor that stepped through rows containing MISSING and UPDATEd the columns with the correct data, but this is no longer viable.

I'm completely stuck on where to look, my brain is frazzled going over this all day! Should I be doing a SELF JOIN? (Bearing in mind that I don't have a column that'll work as a unique identifier)

I apologise if this looks like a lazy ask, I'm quite new to all this and, if someone can't spot an fix that might be staring me straight in the face, then a pointer as to where/how I could implement a fix would be massively appreciated.

If I haven't written this or explained myself very well please let me know and I will edit the post.

ps. Been using the questions and answers here on StackOverflow for years - time to ask my first question!

Comment: Please add some sample data (as it appears in the database) as well as table schema and your query.

Comment: How would you handle a situation where with two rows with `Description2`="Desc11"  with differening `Number` or `Description` - which is the right row to use for the missing data? And does "Missing" actually mean the value *Missing* or presumably the columns are NULL - if so supply the data as it actually is.

Comment: If you're looking to create duplicate rows, just so you can combine them later with a `GROUP BY`, why not just filter out the incomplete rows in the first place?

Comment: I do not understand well how you expect the data to turn out, you could add the expected result.

Comment: @Stu  Sorry I realise I've asked the question quite horrendously. I'll try to provide some further clarification and I'll edit the original question to amend the tables.

The actual table in question contains 20+ columns. The Name column would be a part description. Number would be a Part Number. Description would be a part description and description2 would be a project description. Further down along the rows there are date values and  monetary values set against these. The BIs use this data by summing the monetary values and grouping the values I've given above.

Comment: It's far from clear what your goal is but if you can populate "missing" data by querying the same table you probably should be looking at de-duping not creating duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
update t1
set t1.Name = t2.Name, t1.Number = t2.Number, t1.Description = t2.Description, t1.Description2 = t2.Description2
from MyTable t1 left join MyTable t2
on t1.description2 = 'MISSING' and t1.Name = t2.Description2
where t1.Description2 = 'MISSING'
```

But be careful, before executing it, take a look at this Fiddle and play with it:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c22bac933c28bed8d9129f4eeca7c980

UPDATE:
This answer was valid for the data in your original question, but you should adapt it to your new data after your update.